# Android IDE Which Version of Eclipse is it running?

Tags: android, eclipse

Where can I find the version of eclipse used by the ADT Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to `help` - `about ADT` - `installation details.` You will find the complete information including the Eclipse build there. Based in the build, you can check which version that is. But it's the latest one I guess.